# Custom JSP tags in Freemarker

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags, freemarker

I'm trying to use the Freemarker template engine to render HTML content on the server side. While a simple template is working, I'm facing problems when I try to use custom jsp taglibs. 
According to the docs, it is pretty straightforward to do if the FreemarkerServlet is being used. It provides a hash entry in the data model for 'JspTaglibs'. In my scenario,it is not possible to use FreemarkerServlets. Is there a way to use custom taglibs without using them? Is it possible to 'mock' the FreemarkerServlet?

Answer (score 0):

Calling JSP tags is not solved outside the `FreemarkerServlet`. I think it would be a substantial work to factor it out from there, and will have some pitfalls too.

Thing is, the `FreemarkerServlet` was added back then to help gradually migrating away from JSP to FTL (that was back in the pre-JSP-2 era, when JSP was relay awkward for MVC). So you could just start replacing one by one your JPS-s with FTL-s. For that to work as smoothly as possible, the FM data-model maps to the standard Servlet scopes, etc. But that's not how you should work with FM ideally, it's a compromise, a hack. But if you do things on the FreeMarker way (a JavaBean or a Map as the data-model), then calling JSP tags can become tricky, as it might get/set things in the request scope for example, that you can't access from FreeMarker.